# Solr on Tomcat or Glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, solr, glassfish

I am new to J2EE and [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) and I wonder that I should run Solr with Tomcat or Glassfish ? I need some advices, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the supported and documented platforms for Solr. Its OK to choose any one of these. Even Jetty can be used in production.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrInstall#Servlet_Container_or_Environment_Specific_Tips

---

Users of either one are well-represented in Stack Overflow (see quick search below), so its unlikely you would be left in the lurch when you face any trouble.

```
4,288 search results for posts containing solr tomcat
3,695 search results for posts containing solr glassfish
```

---

Myself, I used only Tomcat. Its as simple as dropping in a simple XML file pointing to your Solr directory in Tomcat's configuration ( http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Multiple_Solr_Webapps ).

I can vouch that Tomcat is straightforward to setup and extend. And (equally true for Glassfish and others) tested and documented for Solr, production-stable and has an active community.

Comment: Regarding your results on Stack Overflow, it maybe means that solr on tomcat has more troubles so it needs to be asked more :D

Comment: Well, its safe to go where there are lots of eyeballs. There will be more questions about serious troubles as well as questions like these. I started answering questions like these when I had 300-ish reps.